# Primefaces calendar date pattern pm and am changed

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a `p:calendar`:

```
<p:calendar showButtonPanel="true" showOn="button" timeZone="#{settingsBL.getTimeZoneIdSet()}" mask="true" pattern="#{searchBL.determineDateTimePatternForField(cc.attrs.curMaskElement)}" />
```

If I click on button current date for locale `de_DE` the value `22.10.15 15:40:37` is set. After submitting the form the calendar shows the value `22.10.15 15:40:37` which is corrent. The pattern is `dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss`. If I switch to locale `en_US` and click the current date button, the calendar input gets `10/22/15 3:43:18 PM`. If I submit or only click on the calendar input field (gets focus) the value gets `1/0/22 1:53:43 1`. The pattern is `M/d/yy h:mm:ss a`. Is this a calendar bug?

I determine the pattern for the locale like this:

```
DateFormat di = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, currentLocale);
if (di instanceof SimpleDateFormat) {
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = (SimpleDateFormat) di;
    this.datePattern = sdf.toPattern();
}
```

I am using primefaces 5.2.14.

Comment: It is also not working with date only. For pattern `M/d/yy` and value `10/22/15` the calendars values is changed to `1/0/22` which is invalid for validation.

Comment: Setting `mask="false"` and it works.

Comment: seems like this bug is still there in PF6. at least it happens to me with pattern="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"

making the mask false worked for me also. thanks for the tip